# Matching Line Thickness in R with Excel

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2

In excel, I have a line plot that has set parameters for line width, such as 1pt for lines on the chart and 0.75 for the axis line width.

I am trying to convert this excel charts into R code, and have run into issues with the thickness of the lines. For example, using a size 0.75 for an axis on a ggplot, geom_line chart in R (see below for one line of the code) is not the same as using 0.75 on an axis excel. Is there any type of chart or table that shows how to match the thickness of lines between R and excel?

```
theme(axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.75, color = "blue"))
```

Comment: have you tried to define `size` as `unit(.25, "cm"))` This defines the line in absolute values  or set `units` in `ggsave`?

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. This is useful and I didn't realize that could be done. I guess I'll need to determine exactly what Excel uses for it's measurement of line width in pts in order to equate the two.